# Kinetic software not working properly

Tags: sdn

In Kinetic SDN software I tried to infect the host so that h1 ping h2 command doesn't work. But it is not working. I don't know what is the problem. I followed each and every step correctly of the Kinetic tutorial given on the net. But still it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

How did you infect the host?
by sending the message through json_sender like given below?

```
python json_sender.py -n infected -l True --flow="{srcip=10.0.0.1}" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 50001
```

In that case make sure that execute the above command in the folder that contains json_sender.py
The default folder is /home/mininet/pyretic/pyretic/kinetic
OR give the the name of complete path+filename in the command like given below

```
python /home/mininet/pyretic/pyretic/kinetic/json_sender.py -n infected -l True --flow="{srcip=10.0.0.1}" -a 127.0.0.1 -p 50001
```